Not root anymore and I am the only user
I hope you are doing great on this Saturday! :D
I have a problem with my User-ID:
It changed from 1 to 1000 and neither I know exactly, where this came from nor what to do to change it.
My guess is my mistake to have been running "cd && chmod 777 -R ." in the terminal. I told me not permitted for every folder, but somehow I think that it comes from there...
I already tried "su passwd root", because my system told me to enter my password and then, that it is the wrong one (which was definitely not).
Please help me to recover the correct status of my system!
Thank you very much already! :)
JTR
Edit: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 JellyJam

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but a user ID is not 1 on install; so your details are unclear. Also it's expected many system utilities will cease functioning with 777 permissions as its outside of what is acceptable, so that was a mistake; so I'll suggest reversing that change. What Ubuntu product/release are you using?  A non-destructive re-install maybe your easiest fix (unless you have good backups, or can script a chmod to restore the permissions to expected/acceptable)

You've added release details (22.04) but not product details (Server? Desktop? flavor).... if it's a Desktop I'd still likely do a non-destructive re-install if you don't have a good backup strategy in place where you can restore file-system data from.

As far as I can tell from the limited description, nothing is actually wrong. Your admin user account UID of 1000 is normal for Ubuntu. This seems like confusion about the differences between root and sudo. Ubuntu is designed to use sudo in most circumstances. Advice: DON'T create a root password unless you are expert and ready for the consequences. Experts don't chmod 777 -R, which --lacking sudo-- merely opened a security hole in your login account.

UID 1 is supposed to be "daemon", a system account.  Check whether that account exists:
$ getent passwd daemon

Did you apply system updates, or run some sort of security tool?
Check your home directory: $ echo $HOME.
If it's something like "/home/myUserName", then you can fix most of the dangerous chmod (never do that :-) damage:
$ find ~ -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 750
$ find ~ ! -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 640

After this immediate problem is fixed, I suggest that you open a new question for whatever problem you were trying to solve with the chmod.
